# What is the standard procedure for implementing a tokenizer from Stanfordcorenlp library?

Tags: tokenize, stanford-nlp, stringtokenizer

Stanford core NLP uses PTB Tokenizer for tokenization. But, I want to implement my own tokenizer. As a part of that, in properties file where we specify annotators, I didn't put tokenize as I want to write Tokenizer myself and put the outputted tokens in 
`CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class` by `set` method so that ssplit would use them later.But, when I try to run this, program is failing saying that ssplit can't be present without tokenizer. I would like to know if there is any procedure for implementing a customized Tokenizer?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you create an Annotator that uses your custom tokenization (the Annotator interface is in edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline) ; for this example we'll call your custom annotator MyTokenizerAnnotator, and assume it is in package org.foo
2. When you build the StanfordCoreNLP pipeline, make sure to add this to the Properties:

   ```
   props.set("customAnnotatorClass.mytokenize" , "org.foo.MyTokenizerAnnotator")
   ```
3. When you set annotators for your pipeline, instead of "tokenize" put "my tokenize"

   ```
   props.set("annotators", "mytokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma")
   ```
4. Make sure to add Annotator.TOKENIZE_REQUIREMENT to the set MyTokenizerAnnotator's requirementsSatisfied() method returns, this will tell the pipeline that your custom tokenizer fulfills the tokenize requirement and will stop the ssplit complaint
5. For your reference , here are the javadocs for some relevant classes, you should definitely look at the implementation of TokenizerAnnotator.java if you're going to build your own tokenizer:

   http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/Annotator.html

   http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/TokenizerAnnotator.html

Please let me know if you need any further assistance!